# Growth of balls given an isometric, proper and cocompact $G$-action on $X$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, curvature

I am reading the paper ["Elliptic and transversally elliptic index theory from the viewpoint of KK-theory"](https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/9246) by G. Kasparov, and I have been trying to understand the following argument, which appears on page 1336, starting at "End of proof of Theorem 5.8". I am mainly concerned with understanding the proof of the following claim:

*Let $X$ be a (Riemannian) manifold and let $G$ be a Lie group acting on $X$ isometric, proper and cocompactly (the latter means $X/G$ is compact). Then, the volume of balls in $X$, as a function of the radius, grows at most exponentially.*

Now, as it is explained in the paper, the properties of the action imply that all sectional curvatures of $X$ are uniformly bounded. I can see that, since $X/G$ is compact, sectional curvatures therein are uniformly bounded. By a lifting argument and with the aid of, for instance, O'Neill's formula for submersions, I can understand that sectional curvatures are uniformly bounded on *horizontal* sections over $X$. I don't see how to extend this argument to all sections over $X$.

The other link I cannot make is the one between the sectional curvature being uniformly bounded and the volume of balls as a function of the radius growing at most exponentially, so any help on that is also welcome.

Comment: The sectional curvature can be considered a map $\kappa \colon Gr_2(TX) \to \mathbb{R}$, where $Gr_2(TX)$ denotes the bundle of tangent $2$-planes of $X$. Since $G$ acts on $X$ by isometries, $\kappa$ is $G$-invariant, and since $G$ acts on $X$ cocompactly, $G$ also acts on $Gr_2(TX)$ cocompactly...

Comment: @Max Thanks for your comment. Could you elaborate more on why $G$ also acts on $Gr_2(TX)$ cocompactly?

Comment: $Gr_2(TX)$ is a fiber bundle over $X$ with compact fibers. So if the $G$-translates of some compact $K$ in $X$ cover $X$, then the set of $2$-planes over $K$ is also a compact set, and its $G$-translates cover $Gr_2(TX)$.